# Excel with data scrollbar

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this excel file that shows a horizontal scroll: I can't see any vba script inside arrow so how does it work when you click on the arrow to scroll since there's no macro associated with it, is it something that exists in standard excel I don't know about ?

see link "Téléchargez un modèle Excel de diagramme de Gantt" on  https://fr.smartsheet.com/les-meilleurs-modeles-excel-pour-la-gestion-de-projet

[image: how does the scroll work?]

Comment: If by "horizontal scroll" you mean that columns `G` and `H` are always on the screen while the rest of the sheets moves left and right, look into `View -> Window -> Freeze Panes`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks but can't see how this explains that action is triggered on arrow click ?

Comment: Where do you mention arrow-click in your question? Please [edit it](https://superuser.com/posts/1430784/edit) to clarify what is actually happening

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad ok I updated.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad also added the spreadsheet see link "Téléchargez un modèle Excel de diagramme de Gantt" on  https://fr.smartsheet.com/les-meilleurs-modeles-excel-pour-la-gestion-de-projet